# Jquery GET method inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

I have an array of links with a url inside them, so I need to call 'get', wait for the response and extract what I want out of it and set an image's src to what I get back

I'm facing a problem where by the time the first 'get' is ready, the loop has finished, so basically every iteration of the loop gets the LAST 'data' response. Basically, only the last iteration of i gets a value, and even that's not always the right answer. It's just the last answer to come back

How do I go about fixing this issue?

```
for(i of instructors) {

    jQuery( document ).ready($.get( i["image-link-post"], function( data ) {

        i['image-link'] = data.guid.rendered;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal reproducible example. And provide an example of expected output..

Answer (score 0):

Since the loop is dealing with async calls, the iteration do not wait for ajax call to complete, and hence by the time the ajax call received a response, `i` is pointing to some other item of iteration. In this case, we need to maintain a local variable of iterating item and then pass the local reference to the ajax response handler. Checkout with below refactored code:

```js
// Changed var image to let image
for (i of instructors) {
    let image = i;
    jQuery(document).ready($.get(image["image-link-post"], function (data) {
        image['image-link'] = data.guid.rendered;
    }));
}
// Below code also works
for (i of instructors) {
    (function (image) {
        jQuery(document).ready($.get(image["image-link-post"], function (data) {
            image['image-link'] = data.guid.rendered;
        }));
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it produced the same behavior unfortunately.
I believe since image is set to i by reference, and i itself changes, then images keeps changing as well :/

Comment: @Bardia I have updated the code. Since `var` makes variable global, it gets updated globally within iteration scope. In this case need to use `let` for image so that it's definition is limited to single iteration scope. I have also added another approach with scoped function. Please check it once.